# CSS HTML Place severel centered divs in td

Tags: css, html

At first, when I say centered, I mean both, vertically and horizontally centered.

I have a table with several tiles (divs) like in Windows 8 with background.images.
Every tile has a centered label (also a div) with a description and a semi transparent background.

Now I'd like to add another div between the tile itself and the label. These div should have a semi-transparent background-color as an overlay of the underlying tile-image-div.

But when I add this overlay-div, my label is not centered horizontally anymore, it is placed at the top of the tile. How can I keep it centered?

This is my code on fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqYnc/) *(please take a look)*

*(The problem in the fiddle code is this line:*

```
<div class="SemiTransOverlay">
```

*When I delete this div everything is centered correctly. 
What do I have to change to keep everything centered and keep div?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all why you are using tables for layout purposes? we are in 21st century, so start using div's and for accomplishing the semi transparent div to place behind the label and vertically aligned label you need to use `position: absolute;` and `top: -50%;`, I've also modified `line-height` for `div.SemiTransLabelGross` and also used `position: relative` and `z-index` properties

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqYnc/8/)

CSS

```
table.Kacheln
{
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border:0px;
}

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

td.KachelFlavourGross01
{
    text-align:center;
    /*background:url(../img/Div/bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;*/
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width:404px;
    height:200px;

}

div.SemiTransOverlay
{   
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.SemiTransLabelGross
{
    font-size:2em;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height:60px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    width:404px;
    height:60px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px; /* Half of height */
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but unfortunately that does not work. The position is absolute and somehow it shoots my whole table. If you change the size of the several windows in fiddle you can see that the overlay stays not fixed.

Comment: @user1567896 Wait I'll check it

Comment: @user1567896 Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/wqYnc/8/ I've wrapped the elements inside a position relative container and used position absolute for label div

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great :)! By the way, you are right about the tables. I use divs in most of the other pages but in this case I thought it would be easier to use a table.

Answer (score -1):

Aligning vertically, what I do is, set `padding` instead of `height`.

eg:

```
div.SemiTransLabelGross
{
    font-size:2em;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height:120%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    width:404px;
    padding: 20px 0; /* removed the height property */
}
```

Sorry for misunderstanding, from the above answer, I think you wanted that light pink div itself to be vertically centered. In that case, add `padding` to its parent.

```
div.SemiTransOverlay
{   
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 20% 0;
}
```

OR, you can add margin to

div.SemiTransLabelGross {
  margin-top: 20%;
}

Comment: This does not work for me, the label div stays at the top nevertheless. By the way, I did not downvote your comment ;).

Comment: @user1567896 you wanted "blah blah" to be vertically aligned, right? I tested on your jsfiddle itself and it worked fine.

Comment: The whole div 'SemiTransLabelGross' should be vertically and horizontally alligned. Mr. Aliens answer works fine for me but many thanks for the nonetheless.